# Estou com problema para para fazer um arquivo.css

Tags: css

Olá, sou novo aqui novo, e estou estudando front-End, mas estou com problemas, quando salvo um arquivo em css, para adicionar no HTML, esse mesmo arquivo fica vazio, mesmo eu salvando ele como (.css) e não muda o que eu editei!
OBs= o arquivo mesmo eu salvando .css o arquivo fica sem extensao. desde ja agradeço!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta usando Bloco de Notas? Se sim, na hora que você for salvar o arquivo, mude a codificação para *Unicode*. No caso dos arquivos já criados você pode usar o *CMD* para renomear.

Comment: Olá, eu uso o sublime, e salvo  o arquivo por ele, mas fica como apenas arquivo!

Comment: Como você está salvando o tipo de arquivo ? Na hora de salvar tem a opção "Tipo", onde é predefinido como "Todos os arquivos", você precisa selecionar o css lá e colocar a extenção .css no nome do seu arquivo.

Comment: Oi, consegui resolver o problem, era um erro bobo meu, mas agradeço a ajuda de todos, como faço para dar ponto ou algo para vcs?

Comment: Algum de nós resolveu seu problema ?

Comment: o problema era um erro na hora de salvar o arquivo, mas oq vale e a intenção!

Comment: Eu só consigo utilizar o sublime abrindo ele como administrador, e não sei o porque disso...

Comment: @LucasOlimpio você mudou a codificação para unicode na hora de salvar para resolver? Ou teve que fazer alguma outra coisa?